# Making multiple Node Express API request calls

Tags: node.js, api, express

I followed this guide https://herewecode.io/blog/step-by-step-guide-create-first-api-with-node-express/ to create a simple Node, Express API and it all works fine, I then changed the API call to interact with SWAPI (Star Wars API). Again all works ok. But my question is if I want to make multiple calls to the SWAPI and get 2 or 3 responses and display them together, how would I do that? is express request the best thing to use?

GitHub for guide: https://github.com/gael-thomas/First-API-With-Node-And-Express-example

Here is my basic app with the API call on the route

Index.js

```js
const express = require('express')
const api_helper = require('./API_helper')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Welcome to Make REST API Calls In Express!'))

app.get('/getAPIResponse', (req, res) => {
  api_helper.make_API_call('https://swapi.dev/api/people/1/')
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response[0])
      res.json(response)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.send(error)
    })
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening on port ${port}!`))

module.exports = app
```

API_helper.js

```js
const request = require('request')

module.exports = {
  make_API_call : function(url){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      request(url, { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
        if (err)
          reject(err)
        resolve(body)
      });
    })
  }
}
```

So where I'm calling https://swapi.dev/api/people/1/ and getting my response how would I call `/people/2/` and `/people/3/` and display them all together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way of doing it with axios, just require it at the top and can have multiple calls and group all the responses together.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
const axios = require("axios")

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Welcome to Make REST API Calls In Express!'))

app.get('/getAPIResponse', (req, res) => {

let one =
"https://swapi.dev/api/people/1/";
let two =
"https://swapi.dev/api/people/2/";
let three =
"https://swapi.dev/api/people/3/";

const requestOne = axios.get(one);
const requestTwo = axios.get(two);
const requestThree = axios.get(three);

axios
  .all([requestOne, requestTwo, requestThree])
  .then(
    axios.spread((...responses) => {
      const responseOne = responses[0].data;
      const responseTwo = responses[1].data;
      const responseThree = responses[2].data;

      const combined = {responseOne, responseTwo, responseThree}

      res.send(combined)
    })
  )
  .catch(errors => {
    // react on errors.
    console.error(errors);
  });
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening on port ${port}!`))

module.exports = app
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
Promise.all([
  api_helper.make_API_call('https://swapi.dev/api/people/1/'),
  api_helper.make_API_call('https://swapi.dev/api/people/2/'),
  api_helper.make_API_call('https://swapi.dev/api/people/3/')
])
.then(function([response1, response2, response3]) {
  // Process the three responses
})
.catch(error => {
  // Error occurred in any of the three requests
  res.send(error)
});
```